# Pylint undefined variable from 'except as'

Tags: python, pylint

I'm getting the following error, I can't see what is wrong.

```
###############  Pylint errors ###############
****** /devwork/code.py:158:11: E0602 test: Undefined variable 'e' 
****** /devwork/code.py:159:23: E0602 test: Undefined variable 'e'
```

```py
    def main():
        integration_logger = logging.getLogger('xxx')
        integration_logger.propogate = False
        LOG(f'Command is {command}')
        try:
            args = args()
            if command() == 'test-module':
                test()
            if command() == 'get-tree':
                results(get_tree(args))
        except Exception as e:     #158
            LOG(e)                 #159
            LOG.print_log()
            raise
```

Comment: As an aside: `propogate` is a typo.

Comment: If I copy your code into my vscode, the except does not error. We would need to see all the code to properly help you figuring out the problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, using pylint 2.13.8, astroid 2.11.5, Python 3.10.4.

Comment: thanks for the spot, i'll change the spelling, i'd have thought it would have errorred there?

Comment: I'll check teh pylint version, it's running from a python3:3.9.7.24076 docker that I have no control over and cannot find the version

Comment: btw, it's running through flake and a few other linters and they don't complain, only pylint.

Comment: To find the version you can do ``pylint --version``, to upgrade pylint you can do ``python3 -m pip install pylint -U``